# The norm of the difference of two projections in a C$^\ast$-algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, c-star-algebras, banach-algebras

> I'm trying to show that if $p$ and $q$ are projections in a
>   $C^*$-algebra (i.e. $p=p^2=p^*$), then the norm of their difference is
>   less than or equal to $1$.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Maybe I miss something, but is this true in general? If $p$ is a non-zero projection, we have $\|p\| = \|p^\ast p\| = \|p\|^2$, hence $\| p \| = 1$. But then $\| p - q \| \leq \| p \| + \| q \| = 1 + 1 = 2$.

Comment: Yeah...what you say is absolutely true ...but it's one of the exercises of the book "an introduction to K-theory for C*algebras" by M.Rordam. Exercise 1, chapter 2.

Answer (score 8):

Let $p$ be a projection in $A$.  Recall that $\sigma(p)\subset\{0,1\}$.  Then in the unitization $A^+$ of $A$, by functional calculus we have 
$$\left\|p-\frac12\right\|\leq\max\left\{\left|0-\frac12\right|,\left|1-\frac12\right|\right\}=\frac12.$$
Thus, for any projections $p,q\in A$, we have
$$\|p-q\|\leq\left\|p-\frac12\right\|+\left\|\frac12-q\right\|\leq1.$$

Comment: Thanks a million!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Represent your algebra faithfully on some Hilbert space $H$. Then consider for $v\in H$:

$$\|(p-q)v\|^2=\|p(1-q)v-(1-p)qv\|^2=\|p(1-q)v\|^2+\|(1-p)qv\|^2$$
where the right equality holds because $p$ and $(1-p)$ project onto orthogonal subspaces. Now further bound each summand:

$$≤\|p\|^2\,\|(1-q)v\|^2+\|1-p\|^2\,\|qv\|^2≤\|(1-q)v\|^2+\|qv\|^2 =\|v\|^2.$$

It follows that $p-q$ is a contraction, hence has norm $≤1$.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!!!